# Token generation success but all data returned

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Generated an embed token using inorder to embed report in my app. Although the token generation is successful my data is returned. Anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Could you give us more detail about your issue? Welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on RLS type You are using to Embed Report, Make Sure You provided username and a role.

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/cloud-rls